# Get BasicAuth creds in Gin

Tags: go, basic-authentication, go-gin

I have made a switch to Gin to try it out. Before the move I accessed the BasicAuth credentials (app_id and token) using the request object like this:

```
appId, token, _ := r.BasicAuth()
```

The `app_id` needs to be found in my database on every call so I'm using Gin middleware for this:

```
func CheckAppId() gin.HandlerFunc {
    return func(c *gin.Context) {
        //how do I access the BasicAuth creds here?
    }
}
```

but I'm not sure how to access the BasicAuth creds without the request object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gin context contains the `http.Request` object in the [`Request` field.](http://godoc.org/github.com/gin-gonic/gin#Context)